# Parsing JSON value from one screen to another in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

i have tried writing a code to send Json data from one screen to another ...
here is my code [fetching data screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV9PM.png)  [the other screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFGT3.png)  [The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gvOu.jpg)

Comment: if you have defined `username` variable using `const` keyword, you can't reassign it. Make sure `username` variable is defined using `let` keyword

Comment: The code image you've provided gives no clue of your problem. The error maybe occurring in other part of your code

Comment: @skmak there's many problems here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to assign a value to a state directly, which CAN'T be modified!
Read more about immutability: https://medium.com/@mustafaskyer/immutability-with-react-native-using-immer-js-fe3dc0e5dc95

When you use `setUserName`, it changes the state for you and rerenders.

Change

```
username = setUserName(responseJson)
```

To

```
setUserName(responseJson)
```

Also, you need to put your fetch inside a lifecycle method, like `useEffect()` (brackets at end is to run `useEffect` hook, only once after component mounting)

```
useEffect(() => {
 //fetch...
}, [])
```

I suggest you to learn more about react before you go further in your project.

Comment: yes, i will do as you suggested ...can you guide me with some good links to follow or a tutorial...

Comment: Thanks a ton, I got it ...what I was doing wrong ......i used the async function and useEffect to read data

Comment: I used this site for 10 years now and it's very well done and free https://openclassrooms.com/en/